# Why program linked against Qt 5.9 cannot run under Qt 5.6?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a program built under Qt 5.9 environment. When I copy the program to a server that is installed with Qt 5.6, the program cannot start, with the following error:

```
./myapp: /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.9' not found (required by ./myapp)
```

But /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 does exist, which is a link to libQt5Core.so.5.6.1.

I think the minor version of .so files won't break the compatibility. How does the string `Qt_5.9' enter into myapp and how does it affect the loading of the program?

Comment: how did you configured/linked your program? Do you use some features which are not available in Qt 5.6?

Comment: _I think the minor version of .so files won't break the compatibility._ This is true concerning functions which already existed in Qt 5.6. However, even minor versions may introduce new functions which might be used in the application. Such applications won't run on older versions.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the code change between Qt5.6 and Qt 5.9 because the program has not even started due to the not found .so. I think maybe the .so loader decides not to load libQt5Core.so.5.6.1 because it does not contain the flag "Qt_5.9" which the program requires. I am not clear about how .so loader loads a .so. Does not it load just by file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor releases of the Qt libraries only maintain **backward binary and source compatibility**, meaning that an older executable will work as is with a newer library (see details [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Version-Compatibility)).

So if you intend to deploy your program on a server with Qt 5.6, it should be compiled with Qt 5.6 or older, and as long as you don't use features introduced in more recent minor releases, you should be able to recompile with an older release without changing anything.

The version symbol "Qt_5.9" or "Qt_5.6" is stored in both the executable and the library. You can use `objdump -p /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5` or `objdump -p ./myapp` to get either the list of versions with which the library is compatible with (every single minor version is listed), under the section "Version Definitions":

```
$ objdump -p /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5

/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5:     file format elf64-x86-64

[...]
Version definitions:
1 0x01 0x00028eb5 libQt5Core.so.5
2 0x00 0x0dcbd2c9 Qt_5_PRIVATE_API
3 0x00 0x00058a25 Qt_5
4 0x00 0x058a2810 Qt_5.0
        Qt_5 
5 0x00 0x058a2811 Qt_5.1
        Qt_5.0 
[...]
19 0x00 0x08a28115 Qt_5.15
        Qt_5.14
```

or the version of the library the executable is compiled for under the section "Version References":

```
$ objdump -p /bin/qtcreator

/bin/qtcreator:     file format elf64-x86-64

[...]    
Version References:
  required from libQt5Gui.so.5:
    0x00058a25 0x00 12 Qt_5
[...]
  required from libQt5Core.so.5:
    0x08a28115 0x00 06 Qt_5.15
    0x00058a25 0x00 02 Qt_5
```

Symbols in ELF binaries may be versioned, which means that a version tag might be added to each symbol and the linker may want to import a symbol with a specific version tag. The "Version" sections in the output of objdump seem to come directly from structures inside the binaries (these structures are described [here](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/symversion.html)).

For the above example, the *qtcreator* binary imports symbols from *libQt5Core.so.5* with both the `Qt_5` and `Qt_5.15` version tags, so the binary depends on a library that defines both of those, which should be the case of any library with a version 5.15 and above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain a bit about the meaning of the output of objdump -p? Why there are two versions:Qt_5.15 and Qt_5 under "required from libQt5Core.so.5"? Does qtcreator require Qt_5.15, or Qt_5, or both?

Comment: @William: I edited my answer with the additional explanation you asked about. I found that there is only one symbol with the tag `Qt_5.15`, which is `qt_version_tag` defined in "qtbase/src/corelib/global/qversiontagging.h", everything else uses the `Qt_5` tag, so this is just a way to prevent version mismatch, not a way to determine which symbol (function, class, class member...) was introduced with a particular minor version, contrary to, for instance, /usr/lib64/libc.so.6, where every symbol seem to be tagged with the minor version of the library that first introduced them.

Answer (score 1):

Qt uses a `major.minor.patch` numbering scheme for Qt releases. For example, Qt 5.0.1 represents the 1st patch release of Qt 5.0. Each release has restrictions on what kind of changes are acceptable, in order to provide a predictable and stable API. This enables users who are only interested in certain types of improvements to be sure that they won't be adversely affected by upgrading to a newer version.

**Major** releases may break backwards binary and source compatibility, although source compatibility may be maintained.

**Minor** releases are backwards binary and source compatible.

**Patch** releases are both backwards and forwards binary and source compatible.

So you cannot run qt `5.9` under qt `5.6`!